# persist e.target when react input is changed

Tags: reactjs

I have an input field that needs to be formatted and have its text highlighted when its focused.
but when i update the state the event does not trigger. i understand why but how do i highlight text of the input after the change?

input

```
<input type="text" value={amount}  onFocus={(e: any) => convertFocusAmount(field, e.target.value, e)} onBlur={(e: any) => convertBlourAmount(field, e.target.value)} />
```

On focus function

```
const convertFocusAmount = (value: string, event:any) => {
    setAmount(value.replace('.', ''));
    event.target.select();
}
```

im all out of ideas, please help

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `event.target.value` on to `convertFocusAmount` instead of just `event`.

**EDIT:**

Do like this:

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={amount}
    onFocus={(e: any) => convertFocusAmount(e)}
    onBlur={(e: any) => convertBlurAmount(e)}
/>
```

And the on focus you have access to the full `event` object:

```
const convertFocusAmount = (event: any) => {
    setAmount(event.target.value.replace('.', ''));
    event.target.select();
}
```

Comment: i am passing both event .target.value and the event

Comment: sure... but as soon the setAmount() triggers the event.target.select function wont work.

i have a suspicion that the react app rerenders and therfor the event.target is null

Comment: Because you are not passing the value on the function. I'll edit my answer again.

Comment: i am parsing the event, but ive tried doing it as you have showed the  issue persists